# Custom Tab in My Account Page Not Showing Up

Tags: magento2, module, tabs, myaccount

I am currently trying to add a tab called "Product in Range" under the My Account section. The tab is showing up on the My Account page but once I click, I get a page not found error.

Can someone please review the code that I currently have and advise what is causing this error?

Here is the structure of my file directory:

[image]

Here is the code that I currently have for the Productrange module I created:

In Index.php:

```
<?php

namespace TimsSuperstore\Productrange\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

routes.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="productrange" frontName="productrange">
            <module name="TimsSuperstore_Productrange" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TimsSuperstore_Productrange" setup_version="2.1.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

customer_account.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">productrange</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Products In Range</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

productrange_front_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Products In Range</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="productrange" template="TimsSuperstore_Productrange::productrange.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

productrange.phtml:

```
<?php echo "Custom Tab Content..!"; ?>

<h1>PHTML CONTENT!</h1>
```

composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "timssuperstore/productrange",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": [
    "BSD-3-Clause"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "TimsSuperstore\\Productrange\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

registration.php:

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'TimsSuperstore_Productrange', __DIR__);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Only  issue in You Code is with controller namespace

```
namespace TimsSuperstore\Productrange\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
```

It Should be

```
namespace TimsSuperstore\Productrange\Controller\Front;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
```

then in your `customer_account.xml` `<arggument name="path">` should be ike this

```
 <arguments>
    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">productrange/front</argument>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Products In Range</argument>
 </arguments>
```

But it won't have to affect tab in my account it is Appreaing fine for me

make sure you have enabled module

```
php bin/magento module:enable TimsSuperstore_Productrange
```

then

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

i have created a sample Module and its working fine you can compare it [GitHub Module](https://github.com/TheRealHunzik/Productrange.git)

Comment: Ah that did the trick! Thanks Waqar, much appreciated!